# Como fazer para aplicação Asp.Net MVC parar de sair do login, e ficar logado direto?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em Asp.Net MVC e esta aplicação quando é efetuado o login e passa um tempo sem mexer, quando vou realizar o cadastro, o sistema pede para logar novamente, gostaria de saber como fazer para ficar logado direto.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esse comportamento esteja atrelado ao tempo de expiração do cookie.
Tem uma propriedade no arquivo `App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs`

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
      ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
   });
```

Altere o valor do configure o valor do ExpireTimeSpan para uma data bem longínqua.